# Set ipv6 for windows with C#

Tags: c#, windows, ipv6

I have a problem with set Ipv6 in windows.
The below code can set a IPv4 address but I can't try to set IPv6.
Please help me.

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
try
{

    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        // Make sure this is a IP enabled device. Not something like memory card or VM Ware
        if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"])
        {
            if (mo["Caption"].Equals(nicName))
            {
                ManagementBaseObject newIP = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                ManagementBaseObject newGate = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                ManagementBaseObject newDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");

                newGate["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { Gateway };
                newGate["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                newIP["IPAddress"] = IpAddresses.Split(',');
                newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { SubnetMask };

                newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = DnsSearchOrder.Split(',');

                ManagementBaseObject setIP = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                ManagementBaseObject setGateways = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGate, null);
                ManagementBaseObject setDNS = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string str = ex.Message;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to set a fixed IPv6 address via WMI, but it does not appear to work (the IPv4 address does work).
The only way I found to do this is by starting netsh from within the code, and using it to set the fixed (static) IPv6 address.  If anyone has a more elegant solution, I will happily use it.  Meanwhile:

Use the .NET System.Diagnostics.Process class to start a netsh process.

The netsh command reference, which tells you the parameters that you need, is [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754516%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

I found that I needed to start a new netsh process for each command that I sent.
For each netsh process, I created a handler for the process's OutputDataReceived event, that logged the netsh feedback.

Comment: yes, I think that "Link Local IPv6" is assigned by MAC address, we can add more but can't change it.

Comment: Have you tried using P/Invoke to the IPHLPAPI.DLL method SetUnicastIpAddressEntry?  I haven't had a need to try it, but it look promising for your needs.